# Lerna problem using conventional commits with an existing project

Tags: semantic-versioning, lerna, conventional-changelog

I've been manually managing my package versions and `changelog.md` file up to the 5.2.0. Now I'm trying to integrate Lerna to manage my package but facing an issue while doing that.

Issue: `lerna version --conventional-commits`,
Lerna is treating it as a first-time version update. As a result, it's including all the commit messages in the changelog as breaking changes and bug fixes, even though I have already maintained a manual `changelog.md` file up to the version 5.2.0 with all the commit messages already present there.

How can I use Lerna in a way that it will not generate the old commit messages as breaking changes and instead expect Lerna to update version as a patch version only 5.2.0 -> 5.2.1 and expect it to only generate commit message after 5.2.0 only. In my case commit message is

```
fix(styles): Automating the versioning using lerna.
Files present in commit messages are
 package.json, package-lock.json, lerna.json,
```

Any assistance in achieving this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's a known problem and was also mentioned in the `lerna version` [docs](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/libs/commands/version), however in the new Lerna these commands docs are hidden away (you can open the command docs from their [website](https://lerna.js.org/docs/api-reference/commands)) or if you use [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite) then all docs are available from the main page.

In the case of your problem, this is the part of the docs that you need, `lerna version` [Tips - conventional-changelog](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/libs/commands/version#generating-initial-changelogs)

Generating Initial Changelogs
If you start using the `--conventional-commits` option after the monorepo has been active for awhile, you can still generate changelogs for previous releases using `conventional-changelog-cli` and `lerna exec`:

```bash
# Lerna does not actually use conventional-changelog-cli, so you need to install it temporarily
npm i -D conventional-changelog-cli
# Documentation: `npx conventional-changelog --help`

# fixed versioning (default)
# run in root, then leaves
npx conventional-changelog --preset angular --release-count 0 --outfile ./CHANGELOG.md --verbose
npx lerna exec --concurrency 1 --stream -- 'conventional-changelog --preset angular --release-count 0 --commit-path $PWD --pkg $PWD/package.json --outfile $PWD/CHANGELOG.md --verbose'

# independent versioning
# (no root changelog)
npx lerna exec --concurrency 1 --stream -- 'conventional-changelog --preset angular --release-count 0 --commit-path $PWD --pkg $PWD/package.json --outfile $PWD/CHANGELOG.md --verbose --lerna-package $LERNA_PACKAGE_NAME'
```